# Accessing Laravel's .env variables inside Inertia.js Vue files

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, inertiajs

I am starting with the Inertia Laravel example https://github.com/drehimself/inertia-example

which is nothing but Laravel with Vue in one monolithic codebase, using Inertia.js:
https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel
https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-vue

I am trying to access Laravel's .env variables inside my .vue component files

.env file:

```
APP_NAME=ABC
```

In app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:

```php
public function register()
{
    Inertia::share('appName', env('APP_NAME'));
}
```

In resources\js\Home.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
        <span class="tw-text-left">{{ appName }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
    "appName",
 ]
}
</script>
```

In my vue console, appName shows up blank. It should show "ABC" but doesn't.
What's going on here, and how I can access all my env variables, ideally without passing everything through the controller, which doesn't seem very efficient?

Comment: Wanted to point out, don't know if you have already corrected. env('APP_NAME ') seems to have an extra space. I believe it should be like env('APP_NAME').

Comment: Yes @N0000B thats been fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it working. Here's how, for those interested:
In AppServiceProvider:

```
        Inertia::share(function () {
            return [
                'app' => [
                    'name' => config('app.name'),
                ],
            ];
        });
```

In your vue file:

```
<template>
<div>
App name: {{ $page.app.name }}
</div>
</template>
```

The 2nd part is what I was missing..I was trying to accept the app.name prop, and was missing $page. 
Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 6):

I know this is kind of old, but I ran into this same issue and the methods above and around the net did not work for me. Something might have changed with Inertia?  Anyway, I did get it working though.

Just like above add the following to the register method within your AppServiceProvider:

```php
Inertia::share('appName', config('app.name'));
// I'm using config, but your could use env
```

Then in your Vue component access the `$inertia` variable like so:

```js
{{ $inertia.page.props.appName }}
```

Comment: Won't this expose the env information from the fronend side? Since it displays as a prop it will be available for everyone. So what if I want to use api key?

Comment: @MostafaSaid Yes, you're right - this will expose the env variable on the client and you **should not** do this for any secret keys. Anyone will be able to see it.

Comment: In Laravel 10, Inertia, Vue3 I can access the env with ```{{ $page.props.appName }}```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation on the author's website](https://reinink.ca/articles/introducing-inertia-js), you need to instruct vue to inject the `page` into your component, and then you can accessed the shared variables.

For example:

```
<template>
  <div>
        <span class="tw-text-left">{{ page.props.appName }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inject: ['page'],
  // ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that, and it results in an error in the console: [Vue warn]: Injection "page" not found
I think that blog post you pointed out is 2 months old, not sure if "inject" is still supported :(

Answer (score 1):

if you want to share multiple variables with view use the following:

```
Inertia::share('app', [
        'name' => config('app.name'),
        'url' => config('app.url'),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using inertia with vite, you can access like below

```
const cek = import.meta.env.VITE_GEO_API_BASE_URL
console.log(cek)
```

you can read more about vite env
https://dev.to/arielmejiadev/load-laravel-env-variables-into-client-code-with-vite-9ld